# JQuery/Javascript unable to display style and image correctly in output

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following output code, which is taking information from a JSON variable and presenting in a map:

```
  marker.info_window_content = place.image  + '<br/>' +"<h4>" + place.name + "</h4>" + place.description  + '<br/>' + place.belongs_to + '<br/>' + '<br/>' + place.categories

self.markers[place.id] = marker
```

The output however is not displaying the image, but instead the link to the image.

Like so:

```
 https://imagelocationishere.jpg
```

I have tried the following, which will show an image icon which makes me think that I am close, but I am still unable to display the image.

```
 '<img src=' + place.image + '/>'
```

How do I adjust so I can display the image, or even just display the output better?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this `'<img src= " ' + place.image + ' " />'`

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Just had the lightbulb moment, then by the time I had made the changes, you had replied. Thanks for confirming what I thought.

Comment: That's great :)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add the double quotes.
Here is the solution:

```
 '<img src= " ' + place.image + ' " />'
```